# Loop through complex JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I have one extremely complex json object, I'm needing to write all the properties and keys out as they are. I've got the concept of it just can't get the execution.

Needing to keep recalling the function if the object has a object and so on. I'm hitting snags though, some of the keys aren't being outputted, some of the values are being broken up as

```
0:h 1:t 2:t 3:p 4: 5:/ 6:/ etc....
name:Travel
scheme:
label:
```

I assume there's a little error somewhere in my code that needs to be changed.

```
ObjectValues = function(obj){
for(var j in obj){
   if(typeof(obj[j]) == "object"){
       for(var k in obj[j]){
         ObjectValues(obj[j][k]);
       }
   } else {
       console.log(j + ":" + obj[j]);
   }
}
```

_

```
{
"title": "Norway Tourism: Wildlife and Nature",
"author": "",
"categories": [
    {
        "name": "Travel",
        "scheme": "",
        "label": ""
    }
],
"countries": [

],
"content": [
    {
    "thumbnails": [
    {
        "audioChannels": 0,
        "audioSampleRate": 0,
        "bitrate": 0,
        "checksums": {
            "md5": "7089E4E044069AE7702DEC686"
        }
      }
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ObjectValues = function(v, k){
  if (typeof v == "object") {
    for (var kp in v) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(v, kp)) {
        ObjectValues(v[kp], k != undefined ? k + "." + kp : kp);
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log(k + ":" + v);
  }
};
```

should work even for JSON values that are not objects.  It will work for

```
ObjectValues(JSON.parse("0"));
```

which would not be handled by the original and it will not iterate over characters in a top-level string if you do `ObjectValues("http://...")`.

Comment: Will fail to print the key "x" in e.g. `ObjectValues( { x:{y:"1"} } )`.

Comment: @frunsi, Really?  Works for me.  In what browser are you testing?

Comment: I think he wants to print the whole hierarchy.

Comment: @frunsi, Fixed I think.  I'm still not sure exactly what is desired.

Comment: This works really well, I'll need to touch it up a bit so it doesn't return 0's on when entering another object. Other than that thanks so much! :D

Comment: @Bankzilla, the 0's occur because of the array boundaries.  You can probably do some massaging to ignore arrays of length 1.

Comment: This is good, but it [prints undefined](http://jsfiddle.net/PMnYW/1/) for the `ObjectValues(str)` call.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen, Good point.  I'm not sure what the right key is to print there.  I think `JSON.parse` with a reviver uses `"_"` as the top level key.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ObjectValues = function(obj) {
    var isArray = obj instanceof Array;
    for (var j in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
            if (typeof(obj[j]) == "object") {
                if(!isArray)
                {
                    console.log(j + ":");
                }
                ObjectValues(obj[j]);
            } else if(!isArray) {
                console.log(j + ":" + obj[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the removed loop.  The way you were splitting it up, you were losing the `k` names.

You should also use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to avoid serializing unwanted keys.

If the value is an object, you still want to serialize the key (e.g. you don't want to lose foo for `{foo: {} }`).

Finally, I had to do an array check, because arrays are objects, and we do want to output the keys nested *within* arrays, but we don't want to output the array indices themselves.

Demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDsjf/5/).

Comment: Won't this still fail for `ObjectValues("http://...")` as in the OP: `0:h 1:t 2:t 3:p 4: 5:/ 6:/ etc....`?

Comment: This was pretty much spot on :D only problem being the categories still get returned like in the example `name:Travel scheme: label:` instead of `categories: name:Travel scheme: label:`

Answer (score 0):

Can't say it's the only problem, but you're missing a comma after the countries array.

Also, for segments like "categories" (and others), are you sure it needs to be wrapped in square braces? In JS terms, that's an array. So I believe you're saying that you have an array, but in this case the only member of that array is an object.

Comment: Those are just snippits of a much larger JSON file. I have no control over how it's being returned sorry, if I did, wouldn't look anything like this :D

Comment: Alrighty. It'll still return type object, but you have to make sure you're drilling into it properly from there. The missing comma, however, is a problem as it creates invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As there is a jquery tag to your question:

I personally use the [jquery.dump](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.dump.js.txt) plugin for such purposes.